# Is there an XPath query that only returns nodes that contain a specific type of data?

Tags: html, xpath

So I am querying a table in an html tree with structure like this:

```
...
<table>
    <tr>
       <td> Some text </td>
       <td> Some more text </td>
       <td><a> Link text </a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

My current XPath query looks like: `'//table/tr/td/text()'` and this would return `['Some text', 'Some more text', '', '']`

Is there some query that could return only the `td` nodes without links in them or even better, is there a query that could return the link text as well? I'd like to get `['Some text', 'Some more text', 'Link text']` from the query.

Comment: Do you really have to use XPath query? These are slow, and you could get this with `[... table.querySelectorAll('td')].map(td=>td.textContent)` faster.

Comment: I don't have to use XPath, but it's relative slowness doesn't bother me and I find XPath to be very readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//table/tr/td//text()
```

returns all descendant text nodes of the td nodes

Comment: Very strange that this ***syntactically wrong and overly verbose*** answer would be upvoted and accepted.   See the [**correct answer here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46256031/290085).

Answer (score 2):

This XPath,

```
//td//text()
```

will select all text node descendants of all `td` elements in the document.